# Trouble with IIS6 ASP application hanging

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I've been meaning to get on here for ages, alas, my recent problem is motivating me, hoping to contribute and not just sponge, but hopefully someone can assist with this issue.

We have two 2003 web servers (looking to upgrade) running IIS6 running multiple ASP.net applications on one web site (via Microsoft NLB).

We have a persistent issue with one application, that is, the white screen of death, the application just hangs, no errors.

Things I have tried / observed:

- Taken servers out of NLB
- Checked HTTPERR for errors at time of issue, some bad requests and connection abandoned by app pool present
- IIS logs show requests coming in
- Checked database for locking PID's or performance, everything ok
- Checked network connections and links to other API's all good
- Checked other websites on server - not working ok
- Event app logs no errors found at exact time of issue
- Split out app pools, found the problem application
- IIS reset and shutting down all IIS process and services gets it working again
- So next when application hung, recycling that specific app pool gets it working for a short period
- 'SOME' parts of the same application will work, even though the main function hangs and gives the white screen of death

Other things to note:

- Server has 4GB ram, terrible I know, 4gb page file, 1.7gb total in use
- CPU usage always <12%
- Resources not 'really' a major factor
- Only one w3wp for this app pool (been running like this for years)

After setting the app pool to recycle on an hourly basis and tweaking some app pool settings, the issue seemed to go away for at least six months. Now it's back for whatever reason, no updates, no changes in application or infrastructure.

- I've upped the worker process for the app pool to 2, the issue still persists after a period of time
- I observed THREE worker process at random intervals when checking not the TWO set up, could be part of the recycle process (one starts up, other shuts down) and I caught it at that moment.
- Killing the highest RAM usage W3WP re-instates application instantly when new process starts up for that app
- Common RAM usage when site failing appears to be apprx 210mb on one of the applications W3WP

I have now set recycling rules instead of hourly to recycle at a more purposeful 200mb. Why this would be a limiting factor I do not know.

I'm struggling to get to the bottom of it, but it doesn't appear to be network, hardware, NLB, Database, or any other core factors. It is specific to a worker process for this app pool hanging / crashing and not processing requests for a certain part of the site.

I am running an effort to upgrade to 2008 in the next few months (version of ESX does not support 2012 and that upgrade is not in scope). However, I'd really like to work out what the issue is rather than using web deploy to deploy a dodgy installation of a legacy application.

Any advice or help appreciated.

Comment: Profiling or hang dump analysis can help. You did too little troubleshooting so far, so it is not likely that the cause can be located yet. Migrating to Windows Server 2008 whose lifecycle ends very soon is not a wise decision. You should also upgrade ESX if it is really old. So in all, unless you run the app in a suitable environment, anything can contribute to the slowness.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lex, unfortunately further upgrades are not in scope even though I would like to. This application will be end of life within 12 months, so I need to find a way to make it stable for the next year. Any recommendation on analysis tool / method would be appreciated.

Comment: I've set up a leak rule for a current w3wp process relating to that app pool, I've also set up a crash rule as well as a HTTP response rule for the site AND a crash rule for the app pool.

Comment: Do you know how to analyze dumps? If not, you would have a hard time learning it, as Microsoft won't support you on IIS 6 dump files. I already told that hang dumps are needed (not leak nor crash), and they should be captured when the web app does hang. It is not a common skill every .NET developers master, so I don't know except migrating to a supported platform by Microsoft, and then open a support case with them there would be an easy way for you. To remedy though, talk to the original developers if you can run the apps in separate app pools.